# Java Sockets - ensure one client connection is served before the others

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have multiple client TCP sockets connecting to a server socket. Nothing unusual about this. On these sockets there is intermittently data coming that the server sockets needs to handle. For some periods, there will be an almost continous flow of data from the clients to the server.

My problem is that I need to ensure that the data coming on one socket connection is serviced by the server before data coming from the others. Only after there is no more data on that "special" connection, I should read data from the other clients.

Right now I have a thread-per-client approach, which I don't think is the best solution for my case. The  thing with the fast "special" connection is kind of a new requirement. So, right now, I'm searching for ways to satisfy this requirement without re-writing the socket handling that I already have.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Wouldn't setting thread priorities be able to give you this? For the regular client create a thread with normal priority, but for the special client create a higher priority thread.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but, by doing that, do I have a guarantee that I will always read the fast connection before the others?

Comment: You are right. Take a look at this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128039/java-threads-priority-in-linux . The link in the answer points to a bug in JVM implementations of thread scheduling. There is also a reference to Effective Java Programming Guide which might have a solution to thread scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement some kind of Scheduling / Quality of Service algorithm. In its easiest form, this could indeed just be "as long as there is data on a special socket, don't bother with the other sockets".

This simple model could be achieved with for example two lists:

1. One list of special sockets
2. One list of regular sockets.

One worker reads sockets, and write into a queue. After reading a small amount of bytes, it checks if the special socket(s) have data. If so, first go read the special sockets, only after continue with the other sockets. The trick is reading data in small enough chunks to be able to switch fast enough, but not too small to lose all efficiency. This is how scheduling for CPU's also works.

Do keep in mind that by only reading special sockets as long as special sockets have data, other sockets might not get read at all. If you don't want this, consider Scheduling Algorithms like **Weighted fair queuing** or **Weighted round robin**.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Konerak you will have to implement some form of QoS.

You could try to define a datatype for you messages that you encapsulate them with and then add tag to annotate that a certain message is of a certain kind (Like your special socket). Then when the server receives a message you could insert the message into queue where you start executing. First execute all the Messages tagged with "special" (or what you want to use) and then proceed to all the messages with no tag. The Queue (FIFO) will ensure that all messages are processed as they were received. Be sure to look at the `Peek` method of a Queue ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html ).

This could work as a quick fix with minimal code change but this could open up a whole new batch of problems. Namely Memory , referring to the size of the queue as other messages won't be removed until the special messages have been processed.

You could also keep the Thread per Client method. It's quite ok in a small environment with only a couple of clients connected but as you start scaling to larger numbers you will need to maybe start consider using NIO. But as I said both are valid approaches each with their own pros an cons.

Just a idea and a couple of things to consider.

Comment: As far as I know (and I don't know too much), using NIO you can specify preferential channels. But switching to NIO would probably require quite some code changes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that why I put at the bottom and tried to think of something that will allow you to do QoS with your current code and minimal change.

Comment: @ovdsrn 'As far as I know (and I don't know too much), using NIO you can specify preferential channels': No you can't. This feature is imaginary.

Comment: Ok so I wasn't crazy been looking for "preferential channels" on Google and could not find it...

Comment: In the beginning of the chapter about NIO of [this book](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780123742551), while arguing for the necessity of NIO, it says something like:

Comment: "If this were all there is to it, NIO might not be needed. Unfortunately, there are other, more subtle challenges involved with using threads for scalability. One is that the programmer
has very little control over which threads receive service when. You can set a Thread instance’s priority (higher-priority threads get preference over lower-priority ones), but ultimately
the priority is just “advice”—which thread is chosen to run next is entirely up to the implementation. "

Comment: "Thus, if a programmer wants to ensure that certain connections get served before others, or impose a specific order of service, threads may make it harder to
do that." From here, I draw the conclusion that is possible with NIO to specify which connection needs to be served first. I will read more carefully the chapter to see how it can be done, too.

Comment: Thanks for the snippets please keep me updated would really like to know about this mysterious feature if it does exist. If you find any links; those would help too.

Comment: @ovdsrn You can't 'specify preferential channels' in NIO. This is a myth. As I said 12 years ago. There is nothing in your quotations that supports your claim.